# link_to check a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, link-to

I have the following code and would like it so that you can click on "delete" it will check the checkbox. Is there a simple solution for this? I can't figure out how to do it with link_to.

```
<%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo_fields| %>
  <% unless photo_fields.object.new_record? %>

    <%= link_to image_tag(photo_fields.object.photo.url(:user_thumbnail)), photo_fields.object.photo.url(:original), class: "fancybox"%>
    <%= photo_fields.check_box :_destroy %> <span> delete  </span>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make the text part of the label for the checkbox, clicking it should toggle the checkbox. For example, change:

```
<%= photo_fields.check_box :_destroy %> <span> delete  </span>
```

to:

```
<label>
  <%= photo_fields.check_box :_destroy %>
  <span> delete  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Wow thanks simple, didn't know about the label tags; I'm a new programmer, cheers.

Comment: Just a note here label causes a line break so do as follows: <label style="display: inline-block;"></label>